# Running VirtualBox in a Xen environment fails

Tags: apt, package-management, virtualbox, xen

So, virtualbox does not get along with `xen`. How do I kill/uninstall/remove `xen` from the terminal so that DKMS process succeeds?

```
aborns@nautilus:~$ sudo apt-get remove xen-hypervisor-4.5-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cpu-checker grub-xen-bin grub-xen-host ipxe-qemu libboost-thread1.58.0
  libfdt1 librados2 librbd1 libspice-server1 libusbredirparser1 libxen-4.5
  libxenstore3.0 msr-tools qemu-block-extra qemu-system-common qemu-system-x86
  qemu-utils seabios xen-utils-4.5 xen-utils-common xenstore-utils
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  xen-hypervisor-4.5-amd64
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1,890 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 208723 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing xen-hypervisor-4.5-amd64 (4.5.1-0ubuntu1.3) ...
Including Xen overrides from /etc/default/grub.d/xen.cfg
WARNING: GRUB_DEFAULT changed to boot into Xen by default!
         Edit /etc/default/grub.d/xen.cfg to avoid this warning.
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-34-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
aborns@nautilus:~$ virtualbox
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (4.2.0-34-generic) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
aborns@nautilus:~$ sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS ...done.
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
  (Running VirtualBox in a Xen environment is not supported)
aborns@nautilus:~$
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get purge 'xen-hypervisor*' && sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: Thanks @heemayl. After your commands and a host restart, this worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `purge` all `xen-hypervisor` related packages:

```
sudo apt-get purge 'xen-hypervisor*'
```

Now remove the packages that were installed as dependencies but no longer required after the above removal action:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

In one go:

```
sudo apt-get purge 'xen-hypervisor*' && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you're running on EC2 or other Xen environment. Uninstalling Xen won't turn your VM into a bare metal server.

Comment: @Cerin Not all solutions carry the generic sense. This solved OP's problem. (If you need help, perhaps you should ask it as a new question).